# How set size of all dialogs in Wix installer?

Tags: wix

I need set width and height of all dialogs in wix installer. I can set size of custom dialogs, but how can change built-in dialogs (WelcomeDlg, etc)?

Comment: Don't know if there's a "proper" way to do this, but you could try creating a new dialog from a direct copy of each existing dialog, then modifying your "new" dialogs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a custom .wxl file. They let you customize size and location of dialogs and controls. http://www.joyofsetup.com/2012/07/14/localizing-more-than-strings-in-wix-v3-6/

Answer (score 0):

Inside .wxl file, use `UI` tag to localize(modify) any control of custom dialogs in WIX UI.

```
<UI Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="50" Height="44" />
<UI Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="BannerBitmap" X="320" Y="0" Width="50" Height="44" />
```

**To know more:**

1. Wix Source Code - https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/
2. UI Elements Info - https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wixloc/ui.html
3. WIX Localization - https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wixloc/wixlocalization.html